# Seeing Maven plugin error after restarting jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After accidental restart of jenkins, was unable to see any plugins in jenkins. So copied plugins from old backup, then restarted jenkins. Now all my plugins seem to be working fine, but I started seeing the following lines of error in a job which uses maven-plugin (build arifact using pom.xml). Unfortunately I'm not having any recent backups to compare. Can someone please help how can we fix this.
Maven version used in the job: 3.3 (same as before).
Jenkins ver. 2.136

````
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenExecutionException: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private final org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.repositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint: 
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1389)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1125)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3084)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to ctlcronagent
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1070)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:986)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:691)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private final org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.repositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint: 
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:131)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:110)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:137)
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1322)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private final org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.repositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.lookup(MavenEmbedder.java:576)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:121)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private final org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.repositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem field org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.repositorySystem to org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    ... 22 more```
````

Comment: I doubt that you have used Maven version 3.3.6 [because this version does not exist](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html). Furthermore which Jenkins version etc. do you use? Don't have use version control to store your setup?

Comment: Edited the description: Jenkins ver. 2.136, Maven version: 3.3

Comment: 2.136 ... wow.. Maven 3.3.??... ? I strongly recommend that you completely upgrade Jenkins as well as Maven...